# How to convert html into Json Obj

Tags: php, html, json

Can anyone tell me please how to convert html code into json obj by using form.

For example:

If this is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="title">#Title 1</div>
<div class="content"><p>Some Content</p></div>
```

I want to convert this into Json obj like

```
[{"title":"#Title 1","content":"<p>some content<\/p>"}]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918249/jquery-html-to-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this tool;

http://json.fastfrag.org/

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, i just googled for you, there are tons of websites who can help you. I found this one in particular very helpfull. It requires Jquery though, and I am not sure if you are familiar with it.

[Convert HTML form to JSON and POST using jQuery](http://exceptionallyexceptionalexceptions.blogspot.nl/2011/12/convert-html-form-to-json.html)